# Reuse streamer Objects

Tags: java, exception, serialization

Below is a code snippet of my project,

```
while (...) {
`   Map <Long,String> eventDataMap = generateEventDataMap(interactionDataJsonObj);`

    ByteArrayOutputStream objOutputStreamer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectStreamer = new ObjectOutputStream(objOutputStreamer);

    objectStreamer.writeObject(eventDataMap);
    objectStreamer.flush();
    objectStreamer.close();
    objOutputStreamer.close();

    byte[] interactionDataBlob = objOutputStreamer.toByteArray();
    //more steps .. byte array inserted into Database

}
```

What I want to do is, not create new ByteArrayOutputStream and ObjectOutputStrem objects for each loop iteration , which is leading to Heap overflow exception.

Is there any way I can take these object creaation step outside and maintaain the functionality of the code.

The thing i tried was -

```
 Map <Long,String> eventDataMap = generateEventDataMap(interactionDataJsonObj);`

    ByteArrayOutputStream objOutputStreamer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectStreamer = new     ObjectOutputStream(objOutputStreamer);

while (...) {

    objectStreamer.writeObject(eventDataMap);
    objectStreamer.flush();

    byte[] interactionDataBlob = objOutputStreamer.toByteArray();

    objectStreamer.reset();
    objOutputStreamer.reset();

}
    objectStreamer.close();
    objOutputStreamer.close();
```

But when I am reading the data written this way I am getting

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720011
```

exception.

Please help/suggest find a way in which i can avoid creaating new objects in the loop.

Thanks

Comment: What you do with the byte array in the loop? You pasted only to the point you obtain it, and then where you put it?

Comment: It is inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

The loop itself, as you posted it here in first version, can't fill the heap, cause both the two streams and the resulting byte array are eligible for garbage collection at the end of each loop iteration.

If you're getting OutOfMemory, either the generateEventDataMap method is leaking, or you're not flushing to the database you're writing to.

Detecting what is leaking is hard without inspecting the heap. Try using a profiler, like jvisualvm or similar, to see what the heap is full of.

Comment: Actually, the byte array becomes very large and the loop is running for a very long time . This module is a part of a parser which parses JSON files and dumpes in to Database.
I used memory leak profilers, which informed me about the leak at the line objectStreamer.writeObject(eventDataMap);

Comment: Sure, a very big byte array can be a problem. You could try writing objectStreamer=null; objOutputStreamer=null; eventDataMap=null; soon after you obtained the byte array, to save some ram. However, if you can stream directly to the database instead of going thru a byte array would be better.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way of storing a Map<Long,String> into database. After retrieving also it should be Map.

Comment: Don't know what database you are using, how you need to access it, there are a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: I am using MySQL as my DBMS, and i need to access it as a Map object itself after retrieving from the database